# Websockets and authentication (Sveltekit)

Tags: security, websocket, sveltekit

I have a Sveltekit application, which uses a IODC flow for login specifically an accesstoken when trying to call APIs.

The accessToken is available in all calls to the backend via cookies, however, cookies are not available when using websockets. I want to be able to transfer the cookie via the websocket protocol to the server, to validate that the user is authenticated.

When the page is loaded a store is created with the user's access token, which is accessible by the browser, meaning I can send it as the first message in the websocket protocol. The issue lies in when the access token expires, I need to reload the entire page to refresh the store as cookies are not accessible by the browser.

I need some mechanism that allows me to send the access token via the websocket protocol in a secure manner. How do I solve this?

My first thought was to make a backend API which simple returns the cookies and then updates the store, but I am pretty sure this has security issues.

I am struggling to find much information about how to make a secure websocket setup between browser and server.

Comment: "cookies are not available when using websockets" - that is just wrong.

Comment: Alright, could you please elaborate on that? 
I am using javascript native websockets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket. Can you give examples of how to send the cookie via websocket clientside to an external websocket server?

Comment: It obeys the same rules as a regular `fetch` request when initiating the connection, so various security policies that apply there also apply here. So if by "external" you mean a different origin, then the cookies may not be sent. If the socket is on the same origin, you do not have to do anything special for the cookies to be sent on the handshake request.